# MFC C++: How to set CTreeCtrl item height on windows mobile

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-mobile

I need to change the height of all items of a CTreeCtrl. On mobile devices with high resolution the space between the items is to big. I found the method CTreeCtrl::SetItemHeight but it seems not to be available on WM5/WM6. Does someone know a way to modify the height?

Comment: Can you set the font smaller? I have not used MFC in WinMobile for years, so I am not sure.

Comment: That is not a good solution, because it is hard to read then.